# UIMA Ruta learning sources and related reading material

Tags: documentation, nlp, uima, ruta

I finished reading UIMA Ruta [official documentation](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.language.conditions.if) which is very helpful. I was wondering whether there is more material on UIMA Ruta to continue my reading (and learning). Could you suggest any other documentation/book/paper/website that you believe is relevant to this scripting language and maybe NLP from that particular view? Until now, I've found and read a paper titled *UIMA Ruta: Rapid development of rule-based information extraction applications*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official documentation is the main and most up-to-date source of information about UIMA Ruta.

The paper *UIMA Ruta: Rapid development of rule-based information extraction applications* provides an overview of the system with some additional information about teleated work and use cases. However, the paper refers to version 2.2.0 as far as I remember. The current version of UIMA Ruta is 2.6.0 meaning the paper is rather outdated concerning the features of the language and integration, e.g., maven. Besides that, it's a good start to read. There are some other papers, which are however subsumed by this one.

There are [slides](https://uima.apache.org/downloads/gscl2013/2013-GSCL-Ruta.pdf) of the tutorial at GSCL 2013 which refer to UIMA Ruta 2.1.0.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta and wrote all the mentioned material.*

Comment: I created training units with some exercises for learning UIMA Ruta, which however are not yet available and currently also not up-to-date. If you are interested, ask me on the UIMA mailing list for it.